# Java EE: implement role management within a web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

What is the cleanest way to offer a role management system for a specific Java EE web application?

All role management approaches I heard from are used to secure the glassfish container itself.
What I want is a role management within a application, i.e. create/remove roles and add specific allowed actions, e.g.: 'show records of Type X', 'remove records from type Y' etc. I.e. I have to be able to manage them within the web app and not within the application server.

Is there any existing solution available?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Security Realm in Glassfish using the administration console. Once you have your security realm open your web.xml and configure your login stuff and a set of security constraint, specifying a list of roles that can access specific paths (in this case the *protected* folder). SO markup is weird below..sorry about this.

```
   <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Area protetta</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Area Protetta</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/protected/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/faces/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-name>broker</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

You can have more than one constraint, with N possibly overlapping roles per constraint. Once you have set up this you may create a section of your web application to change the user role. When you update a user role his/her permission are updated accordingly.

In this way you're able to handle the group in your app, but you're delegating the security checks to Glassfish. If it's the first time you do it, it can be an error prone process. Feel free to update your post with your progresses and I'll help.

Comment: hmmmm. I don't want to handle access to specific resources (files) but only to specific functions. In web view for example I want to hide specific buttons (e.g. "create entity") if the user is not allowed to do that. On server side this has to be checked again. My requirements: users have roles, role=set of accessrights. users and roles should be managable within the web-app.

Comment: This is feasible but it depends on the technology you use for the view. Are you using JSF?

Comment: Well this is an important aspect: I don't want to secure url-patterns but functionality. I solved it by using interceptors and filters checking the credentials by using a session bean holding the users & roles.